# Unable to toggle the visibility property on hover in CSS

Tags: css

(Testing in Chrome)

In the below CSS, I'm trying to toggle the visibility of a P-tag when the mouse hovers over it. It's hidden but becomes visible on hover with a yellow highlight.

```
p {
    visibility: hidden;
}

p:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
    text-decoration: overline;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

But this isn't working; the P element is always hidden. I verified that if I remove the first definition, then the hover works, but I need to hide it most of the time.

Comment: how do you hover a hidden element?

Comment: If CSS is impossible, any suggestions on how to toggle this visibility on hover?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest toggling the [`opacity` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) instead.

```css
p {
    opacity: 0;
}
p:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
    text-decoration: overline;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam accumsan, orci ut posuere aliquet, libero erat vestibulum ligula, nec eleifend sapien nunc eu leo. Mauris ligula sapien, posuere eu ligula et, tincidunt pharetra velit. Pellentesque volutpat elit sed mollis lacinia. Donec nunc diam, viverra vel sapien non, dictum faucibus nibh. Donec dictum nec diam non sagittis. Quisque eget arcu et nunc lobortis accumsan vitae vel urna. Vivamus semper mollis auctor. Donec tempus, lectus quis maximus gravida, arcu lorem sollicitudin elit, nec sollicitudin sem neque a felis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse vehicula, nibh vel euismod fringilla, mi lorem luctus dui, viverra efficitur diam sapien sit amet mi. Maecenas sed laoreet mauris. Nunc sodales, mi eu vulputate ullamcorper, ligula augue imperdiet massa, vitae fringilla tellus lorem id dui. In dapibus arcu nec felis porttitor varius.</p>
```

In doing so, the element will still consume the same amount of space when it isn't visible. In other words, the hidden text will continue to behave similarly to text hidden with `visibility: hidden`.